# Java method can implement interface with method having same parameters but different name

Tags: java

I find something quite strange in Java. Let say I have an interface A:

```
public interface A{
  public void doSth(int a, int b);
}
```

Then I have another class B:

```
public class B{
  public void doSthElse(int a, int b){
    // do sth
  }
}
```

I find that I am allowed to do this:

```
B b = new B();
A a = b::doSthElse;
```

Which rule can explain this behavior? And why Java would allow such thing to happen?

Comment: `A` is a functional interface, which can be implemented by a lambda or a method reference.

Comment: Maybe run javap to see what the compiler turns this into.

Comment: "Which rule?" I believe it is [Java Language Specification 15.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `A` interface is factually a functional interface (which doesn't need to be annotated as such, although it generally helps).

When you assign a method reference (with `::`) to your `A` object, it uses `A` as a functional interface whose implementation will be `B`'s `doSthElse` method body.

In other words, if you invoke `a.doSmth` it will run `b.doSthElse` with your arguments.

The equivalent with a lambda expression would be:

```
A a = (x,y) -> b.doSthElse(x,y);
```

- Some docs on functional interfaces [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html).
- Some docs on method references [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).